# Add name and value attribute to checkbox + using Laravel

Tags: php, checkbox, foreach, laravel-5

I have a problem with passing data with my checkbox to my controller.

```
@foreach($products $product)
    <tr>
         <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  name="id[]" value="{{$product->id}}">
         </td>
         <td>{{ $product->name  }}</td>
         <td>{{ $product->tld  }}</td>
         <td>
            @foreach($product->tags as $tag)
                {{$tag->name}},
            @endforeach
         </td>
         <td>{{ $product->created_at->format('d.m.y')  }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Outsite of my foreach loop, I'm defining the column names and there is where my problem starts. The first ( only important ) column is just for checkboxes

```
<th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true" data-sortable="false"></th>
```

If you see insite of my foreach loop, you will notice that there allready is a checkbox field. If I'm removing this checkbox ( the one outsite of my foreach), my whole table gets muddled up

I wan't to remove the input checkbox field in my foreach loop. I also want to add  those two attributes : `name="id[]" value="{{$product->id}}"` to my checkbox coloumn field.

the checkbox allready have a name attribute `( name="btSelectAll" )` and I couln't overwrite it. I also haven't an idea how I can pass the product->id inside a value attribute..

At the end I just want to have the option to manually choose one or many checkboxes, or all at the same time and passing every single `product->id` to my controller.

Does anybody know a good solution or something?

Thanks alot for taking time and I'm really sorry for my bad english :)

Comment: correct your foreach loop @foreach($products as $product) instead of @foreach($products $product)

Comment: that was just a copy and paste mistake - not solving the main problem